# Pandas : Get a column value where another column is the minimum in a sub-grouping

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have :

```
SM  Week  Capacity
A    0     1000
A    1     110
B    1      980
B    2      89
B    3      89
```

And I want to get :

```
SM  Week  Capacity
A    0     1000
B    1     980
```

In other words, I want to get only the rows where the week is the minimum in the group defined by SM. 
How can I do this in pandas, outside of iterating row by row to check manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `df.loc[df.groupby("SM")["Week"].idxmin()]`

Comment: @jezrael awesome thanks learnt something new today!